# HTML google map add custom div as marker

Tags: html, css, google-maps

I need to implement map and custom marker as shown [here](http://bluefaqs.com/2016/02/how-to-animate-a-map-location-marker-with-css/) , here is the map implementation html http://jsfiddle.net/4a87k/ But no idea how to add custom css as marker.

```
<head>
    <style>
      /* Always set the map height explicitly to define the size of the div
       * element that contains the map. */
      #map {
        height: 100%;
      }
      /* Optional: Makes the sample page fill the window. */
      html, body {
        height: 100%;
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
      }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="map"></div>
    <script>

      function initMap() {
        var myLatLng = {lat: -25.363, lng: 131.044};

        var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
          zoom: 4,
          center: myLatLng
        });

        var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
          position: myLatLng,
          map: map,
        });
      }
    </script>
    <script async defer
    src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false&callback=initMap">
    </script>
  </body>
```

Answer (score 2):

The documentation for customising markers is very good, [find it here](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/markers).

And a simple example is to link to a png file directly for the marker, but you can do more with this with [Custom Markers](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/custom-markers) in the api:

```
function initMap() {
  var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
    zoom: 4,
    center: {lat: -33, lng: 151}
  });
      var image = 'https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/full/images/beachflag.png';
      var beachMarker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: {lat: -33.890, lng: 151.274},
        map: map,
        icon: image
      });
    }
```

Comment: I found the example, actually I need animation as marker instead of png.

Comment: @CodeDezk animate a marker instructions are here: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/markers#animate

Comment: Specifically this line: "animation: google.maps.Animation.DROP"

Comment: Thanks for the feedback, I am trying to implement animation as I have shown in above link in question.

Comment: Update your var marker with the example from the Google api documentation site and it should work.